# Strange text with response from ajax in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, web

I have a web application which answers an ajax call with a simple json code:

```
"{"message":"success","success":true}
```

however in google chrome on windows there is a strange piece of text being appended to that response:

```
"{"message":"success","success":true}<embed id="embed_npwlo" type="application/npwlo" height="0">"
```

I have no idea from where does that come from, please any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if that comes from a Chrome extension you have installed?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else in your json file? Other than that, I'd agree with j08691, it's probably an extension adding some content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sugestions I've finnaly found that the guilty was the hp's website logon extension. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have similar. But how come it appears only on sites I'm developing